# Can I run multiple DCount statements on one command button?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm using the following code to count null values in my field called FirstName and display the results in a textbox. Can I add annother field "LastName" and have two results statements displayed in the textbox? I've worked on this for hours. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", "FirstName" & " Is Null")
TxtShowNull = intCountNull & " null values found in FirstName"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure how well I understand the question.  Is this anything like what you're looking for?

```
intCountNullFirst = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", "FirstName Is Null")
intCountNullLast = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", "LastName Is Null")
strMsg = intCountNullFirst & " null values found in FirstName; " & _
    intCountNullLast & " null values found in LastName"
Me.TxtShowNull = strMsg
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly when I removed the " before the 3rd line of code:
    "intCountNullLast & " null values found in LastName"